# TypeError in Firebase function does not log an Error in Logs Explorer

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Using Firebase cloud functions with Javascript on a Blaze plan. Here are two log lines from `Logs Explorer`:

[image: TypeError as debug]

The function execution is stopped by a `TypeError` exception, but the associated logs respectively have the `Default` and `Debug` severity levels, making them hard to spot in the logs.

This prevents from using GCP's [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting) service to monitor Firebase cloud functions, since it would ignore these errors.

A workaround is to create a log based metric with a filter like

```
resource.type="cloud_function"
(severity>=ERROR OR textPayload:"finished with status: 'error'")
```

and to set an alarm with notifications on it.

Do you experience the same issue, should it be considered as a firebase functions bug?

Comment: If this is a HTTPS Callable cloud function, this would be "working as intended" as callable functions return exceptions to their caller all the time where the client side handles the exception.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. However, in this case it is a `database.ref().onWrite()` realtime database trigger function.

Comment: You can try [Cloud Functions logger SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#logger-sdk) to get different level of logs

Comment: @RoopaM Yes, I already use this API to log specific messages.

However, here, we are not talking about logging, but about an unexpected error raised in the code, with no `try/catch` block around it, that terminates the function.
A pretty severe case that I would like to be able to filter out using the `Error` severity level and the `Error Reporting` service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, there exists a feature request for a similar issue in [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/190583824). Feel free to add your concern over this issue.